# the latex code for the matrix in the image?

Tags: matrices

Could you write down the latex code for the matrix in the image? It would be great if the matrix is in bold face...

[image: Could you write down the latex code for the matrix in the image?]

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. Excuse me but what is your contribute? This is not a site "do this for me". I add a link to create a matrix https://jasonwarta.github.io/latex-matrix/

Comment: You might look up \vdots, \dots (used), \cdots (better), and \fbox{\textbf{T}}.